# Dynamically import a library with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to dynamically import a library into my next.js project? or have it load in after the initial page load? I'm looking to dynamically import the toastify library below as it's not really needed until someone clicks on an element on the page.

Tried the following but no luck:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const { ToastContainer, toast } = dynamic(import('react-toastify'), { ssr: false });
```

Comment: Didn't [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) help you?

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic imports in **Nextjs**

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'))
```

Named imports
`../components/hello.js`

```js
export function Hello() {
  return <p>Hello!</p>
}
```

**import**

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.Hello)
)
```

multiple Named imports
`../components/hello.js`

```js
export function Hello() {
  return <p>Hello!</p>
}
export function By() {
  return <p>By!</p>
}
```

**import**

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const {Hello,By}= dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod),{ssr:false}
)
```

Comment: What about with typescript?

Comment: is the ssr false necessary?

Comment: ssr false means the component will not be rendered on server,.